# RegEx no Delphi

Tags: delphi, regex

Uma ajuda com expressões regulares no Delphi 10 por favor. Preciso verificar o seguinte numa `string`:

1. Tamanho variando no mínimo de 6 caracteres ao máximo de 20 caracteres;
2. Tipo de caracteres: a-z ou A-Z ou 0-9 ou _ (caracter "underline");
3. Os carateres permitidos podem estar em qualquer posição e em qualquer quantidade (até o limite da string, claro);

## Exemplos

Strings **VÁLIDAS**:

```
AaaaaaaaBCCcc654_qq
1111s123AaBCcc654_qq
____ds4___xx
12345_123
```

Strings **INVÁLIDAS**:

```
12345-123            (tem hífen)
asdkdn  092834sdfdf  (tem espaco em branco)
$123.0               (tem "$" e ".")
```

Tentei coisas como essas, mas não funcionaram:

```
var ret: TMatch;
begin
   ret := TRegEx.Match(Edit1.Text, '([a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[-]?)', [roIgnoreCase]);
```

ou

```
   ret := TRegEx.Match(Edit1.Text, '(\w*)', [roIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: Veja se esta ajuda. Não sou muito bom em regex mas fiz um esforço aqui: `[^\w]|[\w]{21}`. Se alguma das duas condições foram atendidas, a string é inválida.

Comment: @Mariano Verdade, não me atentei a isso... vou tentar melhorar

Comment: @Mariano Veja este: `[^\w]|[\w]{21}|^[\w]{6}$`

Comment: @Mariano O seu regex deu certo pra positivo, o meu pra negativo. Sim, o meu invalida se houver menos de 6 e maior que 20

Comment: @Mariano na verdade, em vez de `{6}`, seria `{5}`: `[^\w]|[\w]{21}|^[\w]{5}$`. Mas eu sou totalmente newba nisso rs... achei esse meu código mt grande pra pouca coisa. valeu!

Comment: Nos caracteres especiais, acentuações são inclusas? Por exemplo: vÁlidas, acentuaÇÕes, etc... Caso deseje inserir caracteres especiais, pode fazê-lo manualmente com a Regex `^[\wàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð']{6,20}$` e a [demo de teste](https://regex101.com/r/2FGTQM/2). Porém tem um jeito mais fácil de fazer isto, usar Unicode.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal. Essas formas que você indicaram também me ajudou a aplicar em outras situações.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Em Delphi, pode usar `\p{L}` para letras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `\w` casa `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` ou `_`.
- Só precisa repetir 6 a 20 vezes, isso é `\w{6,20}`
- Desde o início da string `^` até o final da string `$`.

Então:

```
^\w{6,20}$
```

E neste caso, é mais fácil usar o método [TRegEx.IsMatch()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.IsMatch)

Código:

```delphi
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
    System.RegularExpressions;

var texto: string;

begin
    texto := 'AaaaaaaaBCCcc654_qq';

    if TRegEx.IsMatch(texto, '^\w{6,20}$') then
        begin
            Writeln(texto, ' é válido');
        end
    else
        begin
            Writeln(texto, ' não é válido');
        end;
end.
```

Comment: Obrigado @Mariano. Funcionou perfeitamente. Uma última pergunta por favor? O caracter `$` não é um indicador de fim de linha apenas? Qual a função dele nessa Regex?

Comment: @wBB `$` corresponde ao final da string por padrão, ou pode ser alterado para corresponder ao fim da linha, usando o modificador [*Multiline*](http://regexpstudio.com/en/regexp_syntax.html#modifier_m), ou seja, com [`RegExprModifierM`](http://regexpstudio.com/en/tregexpr_interface.html#global-constants) ou usando [`(?m)`](http://regexpstudio.com/en/regexp_syntax.html#perl-extensions) na expressão. O mesmo vale para `^`. Se quiser, pode usar `\A` e `\z`, que sempre corresponde ao início / fim da string, independentemente do modificador.

Comment: @wBB Uma expressão regular corresponde ao texto **em qualquer lugar na string**. Portanto, `\w{6,20}` pode casar os primeiros 20 caracteres de uma string maior... `^` e `$` correspondem **as posições** de início / fim da string, e asseguram que coincida com a string inteira, isto é que o tamanho é entre 6 e 20.

Comment: Vou treinar um pouco de Regex para desmistificar... Não pensei que fosse obrigatório o uso desses caracteres de início e fim, portanto minha Regex não funcionaria nunca. Obrigado.

Comment: @wBB É obrigatório somente se deseja corresponder a string inteira, e não com uma parte dela.

Comment: Sim... como eu não estava usando esses caracteres, então estavam sendo validadas coisas que não deveriam ser validadas e por isso eu não conseguia corrigir o problema.

Comment: @wBB Exato..:-)

Comment: Muito bom @Mariano ótimas explicações, parabéns :D